# How to use aar library in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, aar

I am using Eclipse with ADT plugin to develop Android applications and I need to use some aar libraries but the ADT doesn't support this type of libraries so my question is.

How can I use aar libraries in Eclipse like Android Studio?